# What should response be when user offers solution for another DBMS?

Tags: discussion

My apologies if this question has been asked before; I searched and did not find it. What should the response be if, for example, the OP asks a question about Oracle (and tagged it correctly from the beginning) and someone offers a solution that works in SQL Server (or MySQL, etc.)? I've generally been downvoting this sort of answer when I see it, and haven't always been leaving a comment as I think it ought to be pretty obvious.

**UPDATE**

I should add that I don't even generally downvote incorrect answers unless they are blatantly incorrect; I try to point out what might be wrong with them instead and help the author correct them. But I think offering a solution for a different RDBMS, say with a different syntax, is pretty blatant.

Comment: If it's incorrect, it's incorrect. Just downvote. =)

Comment: Is the answer of "In MySQL you do XYZ" useful for a question of "How do you do something in Oracle?"  If not, mouse over the down vote button, read the alt-text and consider how you wish to vote based on that guidance.  It says nothing about correct or incorrect.

Comment: Downvote, comment, move on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voting is your way of indicating whether or not an answer is useful.  If you think that the answer using a different DBMS isn't useful, then by all means, downvote.

If you want to comment you can, but you certainly aren't obligated to.